# Starting a blog, part 3

Tags: discussion, blog

After [I volunteered](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2639/29146) to manage our blog, I've put together [a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqJp--AmlmdwdEJSRVVBcEhjRGpXTzlBeVQtUDIya3c&usp=sharing)* that includes a list of users that said they'd be willing to participate in the blog in some form, plus additional information about specifically what they'd be willing to do. It also includes a draft of the schedule, on a second sheet.

The idea behind the schedule is that we will follow it (for four weeks, as of now), and then start again. The fourth entry is for anyone who said that they would contribute, but not regularly. The idea is that at first, we will roll with a three-week calendar cycle (dropping the unspecified person), until we accumulate some drafts that we can start publishing when the fourth slot rolls around. At that point, we'll switch to the four-week calendar cycle. Make sense, ish?

Every cycle, you will be paired with an editor. In the spreadsheet's draft schedule, every writer is paired with the same editor every cycle, but I'll probably switch it up every cycle in the final schedule.

Depending on if anyone else says that they'd be interested, you may write less frequently.

Answer or comment if you have any objections. The spreadsheet is editable to the public, so if something isn't right with the users list (or if you aren't listed and wish to be), just go ahead and edit it.

<sup>*Yes, I know it's Google. Centralized, data-sucking, proprietary Google. Not all of us have our own ownCloud instances (yet), though; if you object on ethical grounds and have an alternative, hit me up with it.</sup>

Comment: Nice. I started to ask SE about this yesterday and then got distracted by work. I'll make sure they see it today

Comment: I added in a couple of people who put their hands up in previous threads: more shoulders to tap...

Comment: @jasonwryan I didn't include them because they haven't responded yet to my comment asking them if they're still interested

Comment: Fair enough. But they had expressed a desire to participate, I'd consider them potential contributors (they may just need more "encouragement").

Comment: @MichaelMrozek any word on this?

Comment: @strugee Haven't heard anything. I'll be more annoying

Comment: This looks to be pretty nice. I'll see what I can do for next week.

Comment: Ok I added myself there, put some things in the notes. Hope I can help you.

Comment: I'm told that SE is working on making the blog, but they're having some problems with their Wordpress install in general. It is happening though

Comment: @MichaelMrozek any word on whether they've fixed the problems?

Comment: @strugee Nope. They've also got to get their designer to make a theme for it. I'll check if I don't hear anything this week

Comment: BTW, if anyone is unaware of it, there is a chat room for the blogs: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs

Comment: Just an update on this - yes we're still waiting on a design. Sorry about the delay.

Comment: thanks. is there an ETA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent a message to the six writers on your list who are still active on SE (including you). You should have it in your SE inbox