# Call For Papers: the blog is ready!

Tags: discussion, blog

A little while ago, the new design for [our blog](http://unix.blogoverflow.com) went up. I've now published the [first post](http://unix.blogoverflow.com/2014/04/getting-started-with-version-controlled-configurations/), so let's write! Remember that even if something would be closed on the main site, it might still make a really good blog post (or series of blog posts)! This is an awesome community; we can come up with lots of juicy stuff to write about.

If you didn't know we had a blog, and are interested in writing, use [the spreadsheet](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2649/starting-a-blog-part-3) to sign up. We could always use more writers.

Comment: I didn't know about the blog. Great work guys! :) too bad my writing skills sucks

Comment: @RSFalcon7 if you have good content, we can help you make it happen. you get an editor and I don't see why we couldn't get two people to edit if you want.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't intend on posting, you might want to drop by and at least leave a comment...