# The blog link still points to the main Stack Exchange blog

Tags: feature-request, bug, blog, top-bar

Even though the blog [is online](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2859/call-for-papers-the-blog-is-ready), the "blog" link in the top bar dropdown still points to blog.stackexchange.com. It should be fixed.

Comment: I think our blog is considered to be in some sort of beta status, not sure if that link changes until the blog is non-beta.

Comment: @derobert yes, that's why we're on unix.blogoverflow.com instead of blog.unix.stackexchange.com. but it changes before we're out of beta; check [apple.se].

Comment: True, and when I look at our blog over at cooking.SE, it's linked in the footer too. And we have a post now, too!

Comment: @derobert YEAH WE DO! \o/

Comment: Superseded? I don't see anything (any more) at http://unix.blogoverflow.com/