# What ever happened to starting a blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

I seem to have a fascination with [topics that were discussed in 2011](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2635) today, but here goes.

It looks like we were [talking](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/662) about [starting](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/743) a blog back in 2011, but the discussion kinda fizzled out. Despite the fact that apparently people weren't that interested, both of those questions seem to have generated a fair amount of interest (based on both answer quality and votes).

Presumably, we are now a bigger, more well-defined and mature community. Should we revisit having a blog? Perhaps we should contact those who answered the "who would write" question, and see if they're still interested. I would certainly be interested in writing (when my school schedule permits). Thoughts?

Comment: In looking through the links you provided, as it is with these things, someone needs to step up and be a coordinator, is where it looks to have died. I might post from time to time but I already have my own established blog and so wouldn't probably provide a lot, beyond editing others or in assisting.

Comment: @slm it might be interesting if we had some sort of syndication, similar to how a lot of planet.*.org sites do it. e.g. you would have a list of RSS feeds, and whenever one of those feeds added a post tagged "stack exchange" (or whatever), that post would show up in the community blog. that way, you could still do your thing but we'd have interesting content.

Comment: I've been taking answers that I write up here and cross posting them on my blog, often expanding an answer there so that it's more expansive. I've got ~2 dozen of these posts that are in various states, and I come back to them as my knowledge grows or I have time or the desire to do them.

Comment: If you hadn't noticed by my answer style, I generally prefer the long form, explaining more of the goings on than most.

Comment: @slm I think that'd still work. it would definitely be on topic - you could put "for more details, see foobar blog post" at the bottom of answers. and yeah, I prefer those answers too - I always enjoy reading your explanations of the internals of things

Comment: [My answer](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/743/starting-a-blog-part-2/875#875) still stands. What we need is someone to kick off the process and keep things going (including begging people for posts). Wink wink nudge nudge.

Comment: @slm Sheesh dude stop teasing us and post a link already!  It's not even in your profile.

Comment: @goldilocks - what's not in my profile?

Comment: @slm o_o Sometimes I miss the obvious. You seem to have a lot of good stuff there...liked the Rob Reid video too.  I'd definitely contribute to a blog here if someone got one going.

Comment: @goldilocks - thanks, I've thought of it, but I kind of wanted to see if one of the younger members would be willing to take the lead on it. I think it would be a good experience for one of them to facilitate ours, and given our season ppl w/in the site + most are professionals it would be fairly easy to manage the schedule, IMO. I don't have additional bandwidth to do the managing, but I'd def. help. Wink wink nudge nudge 2 person that asked the Q 8-)

Comment: @slm http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/2639/29146

Comment: @strugee - look at this way, you get to boss everyone around 8-)

Comment: @slm \o/ that's the dream!

Answer (score 1):

The 'Question of the Week' series of posts at security.stackexchange.com works very well, and might be a model for us here.

Answer (score 0):

I most likely have the time to create a blog and bother people to bring posts, doesn't sound too hard :). Unfortunately I have 0 experience with bloging, blog software etc. So, anybody got some recommendations (-> Comment or Email an@steamnet.de )?

Comment: a) the Stack Exchange team will set up a blog for us; we don't have to run the server ourselves. b) I've already volunteered, but if you want to create some posts, that'd be lovely! see http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/2649/29146